# Conflicting info about version installed, latest version available and failure during update

Tags: linux, azure, upgrade, azure-cli

I am running azure CLI on Linux.

```
uname -a
Linux kali 5.15.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.15-2kali1 (2022-01-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running `az --version` command shows I have version `2.36.0` installed and there are updates available.

```
az --version                                                                   
azure-cli                         2.36.0 *
 
core                              2.36.0 *
telemetry                          1.0.6
 
Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.24.0
 
Dependencies:
msal                              1.17.0
azure-mgmt-resource               21.0.0
 
Python location '/usr/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/kali/.azure/cliextensions'
Extensions system directory '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure-cli-extensions'
 
Python (Linux) 3.9.12 (main, Mar 24 2022, 13:02:21) 
[GCC 11.2.0]
 
Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal
 
 
You have 2 updates available. Consider updating your CLI installation with 'az upgrade'
 
Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azureclihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
```

However, when I run the `az upgrade` command, it seems to have conflicting statements about what's the latest version (2.37.0, 2.36.0-1).

```
az upgrade  
This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus                                                                  
Your current Azure CLI version is 2.36.0. Latest version available is 2.37.0.
Please check the release notes first: https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli                                                                            
Do you want to continue? (Y/n): y
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
azure-cli is already the newest version (2.36.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
CLI upgrade failed or aborted.
```

Two questions.

1. Why `az --version` is showing version `2.36.0` installed while az upgrade states, I have `2.36.0-1`?
2. Why its not able to upgrade to `2.37.0`?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why  `az --version`  is showing version  `2.36.0`  installed while az upgrade states, I have  `2.36.0-1`?

After executing the az update command it retruns
**`azure-cli is already the newest version (2.36.0-1).`** it shows that it is not updating to 2.37.0 version.

> 2. Why its not able to upgrade to  `2.37.0`?

As long as installation is supported, **az upgrade** is supported on **Windows, macOS,** and **some Linux distributions**. It only allows you to ***upgrade to the most recent version***.

**If you're using Azure Cloud Shell to execute the Azure CLI, you're probably already utilizing the most recent Azure CLI installation**. You must wait for the next build of Azure Cloud Shell unless there is an ad-hoc release of a small bug fix version, as **az upgrade is not supported in Azure Cloud Shell**.

Running az upgrade will verify and update all installed extensions if azure-cli is already the most recent version.

#### To achieve this, you can use the below workaround:

The **az upgrade** command is still in preview mode. currently it is working in **PowerShell Session**. It's **not working in Azure CLI session**.

In your Linux Environment either you have to use **az upgrade** or **apt-get upgrade** command to update the latest version.

```bash
# using az command
az upgrade
 (or)
# using apt-get command
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The **apt-get upgrade** command upgrades all of your system's installed packages that haven't had their dependencies changed.
**Use `apt-get install` to upgrade only the CLI.**

OR enable the [auto update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli#automatic-update) to avoid this kind of conflicts

#### Reference

1. [Az cli update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli#manual-update)
2. [Using Az upgrade command in cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/601803/whenever-i-run-commands-in-the-cloud-shell-i-alway.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not sure if any of this answer the questions I raised. I guess my point what why two different command reporting two different versions installed on my device (2.36.0 vs 2.36.0-1) . I try using the apt-get update and upgrade commands too and still couldn't update to latest version. Also I don't understand references to Azure Cloud Shell as I am not using shell at all.

Comment: I tried my end I am able to update the version. Please try to uninstall and install the recent version. It may solve your problem.